# is it possible to add own csv or txt file while working with shiny package to make own dashboard for visualisation

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I am preparing a dashboard using shiny and shiny dashboard package ,now i want to add my data to prepare a visualization.How to implement it.this is the a layout plan of the app .

```
    ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Row layout"),
  dashboardSidebar(),
 dashboardBody()
)


 server <- function(input, output) { 

driver.csv <- read.csv("E:/RMARKDOWN/driver.csv.csv", fileEncoding = "UTF-8")

  New_DataSet1<-data.frame(driver.csv$ï..Year_AG,driver.csv$Severity_Desc,driver.csv$Injury.Type)
  New_DataSet1

  latest <- New_DataSet1[1:100,]
  latest

  d <- aggregate(latest$driver.csv.Injury.Type,  by=list(chkID = latest$driver.csv.Severity_Desc), FUN=sum)
  #barplot(d)
  renderplot(d$x)
  #barplot(d$x, xlab = d$chkID)
 # barplot(d$x, names.arg = d$chkID)

 }

 shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Comment: You should add some information about what your data looks like and what you expect your plot to look like.

Comment: Yes, it is possible to add own csv or text file while working with shiny package. I have added solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54474561/rshiny-creation-of-bar-plot-using-csv-file/54474722#54474722