# Rshiny--creation of bar plot using CSV file

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I want the bar plot to be embedded into application.output of vector d is giving me result I want that to be embedded into shinyapp and later I want to make it interactive too.

```
 library(ggplot2)

 driver1 <- read.csv("E:/RMARKDOWN/shiny/driver.csv",header = T)

 New_DataSet1<- 
 data.frame(driver1$ï..Year_AG,driver1$Severity_Desc,driver1$Injury.Type)
  New_DataSet1

  latest <- New_DataSet1[1:100,]
  latest

  d <- aggregate(latest$driver1.Injury.Type,  by=list(chkID = 
       latest$driver1.Severity_Desc), FUN=sum)


 ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Row layout"),
   dashboardSidebar(),
    dashboardBody()
      )


  server <- function(input, output) { 

   #output$plot <- renderPlot({    barplot(d$x, xlab = d$chkID)  })

  renderPlot(d$x)
  #barplot(d$x, xlab = d$chkID)
 # barplot(d$x, names.arg = d$chkID)

  }

      shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Comment: I have added solution for you. Could you please check and let me know in case of further information!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read file first and render it using bar chart as below:

```
library(plotly)
library(shiny)


ui <- fluidPage(
  mainPanel(
    plotlyOutput("chart")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$chart <- renderPlotly({
    # write code here to read data from csv file
    df=read.csv("")

    # Set x and y axis and display data in bar chart using plotly
    p <- plot_ly( x = iris$Species,
                  y = iris$Sepal.Length,
                  name = "Iris data",
                  type = "bar") 
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Screenshot from working demo:
[image]

Comment: is it possible to make it interactive using another field and this bar plot should change.....

Comment: @nitisethi: Yes it is possible. Kindly consider to mark this answer as accepted if it is working for you. Thank you

Comment: I would prefer to ask new question with detailed information.